# How to Log to Console During Ant Testing Task

Tags: java, ant, log4j

I have an ant task to run unit tests.  It looks like this

```
<target name="test-platform" depends="compile_tests">
    <mkdir dir="${platform.test.log.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="true" haltonerror="true">
        <classpath refid="test.build.classpath"/>
        <batchtest todir="${platform.test.log.dir}">
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="true"/>
            <fileset dir="${javatests}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

I have some test that looks like this:

```
public class UserTest  extends BaseTestClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BaseTestClass.class);

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testUser() {
        List<User> users = sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from User")
            .list();
        for(User user : users) {
            LOGGER.info(user.getName());
            Assert.assertEquals(user.getName(),String.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I had created this BaseTestClass to contain a log4j configuration follow several other SO posts.

```
package com.example.test;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
public class BaseTestClass {
    static {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }
}
```

But when I run my tests, nothing comes out in the console.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Per : http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html , try with setting `showoutput="true"` and log4j reference can be explicitly passed with `<jvmarg value="-Dlog4j.configuration=file>`

Comment: Hm unfortunately this seems to send EVERYTHING to the console including verbose hibernate output.

Comment: @DavidWilliams Then you could use : junitreport ant task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html and expand the failure to see related exception in htm report

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get up and running:

Create a log4j.properties file and put it in the root of your class path.

enter the following lines.  The pattern you use is up to you.

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, Console

log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %5p %m%n
```

You may need to remove BaseTestClass.

Comment: He Simon, thanks for the answer, let me try that.  I am going to first attempt to place the log4j.properties in my test directory resources directory which is in the classpath.  I anticipate a hurdle with regard to what you mentioned as the "root" of the classpath.

Comment: Still nothing comes out on the screen.  I tried both `<junit fork="true">` and `<junit fork="false">` and the log4j.properties both in the top of my test directory and in the resources directory next to  my test-applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

An even quicker way:

```
<junit showoutput="true">
<formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${src.tests}"></fileset>
</batchtest>
```

The `usefile` attribute is the game-changer here.

Reference from the [Apache Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

> ... Output will always be sent to a file, unless you set the usefile attribute to false.